# VS2010 project showing with x86 platform

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, desktop-application

working in Visual Studio 2010 i have a 3 class on libraries and 1 web project. all are on All CPU platform. i added a windows application as Parser but its platform is automatically x86.

[image: Config Manager]

more over, when i referenced the other libraries in parser project it took it un referenced. plz let me know if i need some configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the project properties of QuizParser (right click on the project and find 'properties' at the bottom) in the solution explorer.

Then find the 'build' tab in the project properties window, and you should be able to change the target platform to any CPU.

Comment: have done it already, now project level is showing anycpu bt still at solution configuration level it shows x86